# Is the 'Anoying Robot' broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Usually the 'Annoying Robot' function posts new questions on '[The BBS](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38597/the-bbs)', but there has been no anouncement of new questions since May 25th.

Any reason to know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BBS had been frozen for inactivity.  The system will do this automatically if no users post anything in chat for a few days.

The *Annoying Robot* doesn't count as a user for this purpose, so its posts were not taken into consideration for freezing.  Once the room was frozen, the robot could not post - again as it is not a regular user.

I have unfrozen the room.  All should return to normal.

Comment: In order to stop such problems from occurring, we should post messages with interesting topics for discussion every so often. :-D